# What can additional keys do after I unlocked all gates?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I've got enough keys to unlock every single gate I see in Ancient Egypt, yet new keys still get dropped when I play in Egypt. I notice the keys are different in Pirate Seas.

I wonder what my extra Egypt keys could do for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is nothing you can do with spare keys.